# Universal links iOS - supporting multiple bundle ids from single domain

Tags: ios

I have odd issue that when I've specified multiple bundle ids in apple-app-site-association-file then all apps has been registered like being able to handle this app link. 
So then if I have 2 apps for client and managers both app open simultaneously. I've heard that apple doesn't enable any chooser to select prefered application like Android. But register the first application?

Problem is that I have app cycle 4 apps installed Dev, Prod x 2 and all 4 apps are cycling and hanging iOS system in this cycle.

Any idea or solution to this problem?

Is there any difference between this two approaches

```
{
                "appID": "9JA89QQLNQ.com.apple.wwdc",
                "paths": [ "/wwdc/news/", "/videos/wwdc/2015/*"]
            },
```

And this one

```
"9JA89QQLNQ.com.apple.wwdc": {
                "paths": [
                    "/wwdc/news/",
                    "/videos/wwdc/2015/*"
                ]
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Problem was that any of this multiple apps could not handle opening link and all return false from continueUserActivity method. So there was infinite loop of always available next app that could not handle this request. It is odd that apple doesn't block such infinite loop and after trying single time each app doesn't redirect to safari browser.